# Dimensions of eigenspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the vector space of $n \times n$- matrices over the field $K$ under addition and let the linear
operator $f$ be given by $f(A) = A^\top$
, where $A^\top$ denotes the transpose of the matrix A.

We know that +1 and -1 are the only eigenvalues of f.

Suppose the characteristic of $K$ is not 2. What are the dimensions of the eigenspaces
$E_1(f)$ and $E_{−1}(f)$?

Comment: try to find out the matrix of the linear map :)

Comment: Figure out what it means to be in either of the eigenspaces: How are matrices $A$ called that satisfy $A = A^{\perp}$, and what if $A = -A^{\perp}$? It shouldn't be too hard to figure out a basis/the dimension for the eigenspaces, once you have done that.

Answer (score 0):

For $A^\top=A$ one can choose all the elements $a_{ij}$ for $i \leq j$. So dimension is $n!$

For $A^\top=-A$ one can choose all the elements $a_{ij}$ for $i < j$ as all the elements on the diagonal must be equal to $0$. So dimension is $(n-1)!$